# Distributing a HTML Document

Tags: html, software-distribution

I am creating a HTML 5 user manual. This contains a number of image folders and js fodlers. Now i wish to distribute this as a single document. In Windows there is mht or something to that effect. Is there any way I can do this on ubuntu that is not browser or OS dependent?

Comment: What do you mean "distribute it as a single document"? Do you want to stuff it all into one file? Why?

Comment: If you _really_ want to, you could base64 encode your images and put them directly in the CSS. Then, get your CSS and JS files and put them in the `<head>` of the HTML file. But really, why?

Comment: Well simply i dont want to email a full folder, rather a single file. I agree it would be better to create a PDF then a set of HTML documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**notice that** :MHTML, short for MIME HTML, is a web page archive format used to bind resources which are typically represented by external links (such as images, Flash animations, Java applets, audio files) together with HTML code into a single file. The content of an MHTML file is encoded as if it were an HTML email message, using the MIME type multipart/related. The first of the file is normally encoded HTML; subsequent parts are additional resources identified by their original URLs and encoded in base64. This format is sometimes referred to as MHT, after the suffix .mht given to such files by default when created by Microsoft Word, Internet Explorer or Opera. MHTML is a proposed standard, circulated in a revised edition in 1999 as RFC 2557.
So try to save document as regular html with none of dependency. this will be run at any OS independently.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know you won't be able to really distribute this manual as HTML OS independent.

BUT: you can distribute it as PDF, ZIP-file, host it anywhere, ePub, etc. These are pretty good options for your needs. Safari has a pretty cool feature called webarchive, but this only zips ONE single page to a viewable, always-the-same-looking page. And it will only be viewable with Safari. So you'd have to do this for ALL your pages...