# How to create MHTML standalone file with same page links

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink, mhtml

How do you export an [MHTML standalone webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444586/distributing-a-html-document/13444636#13444636) from google chrome that has correctly operating [*same page* links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)?

For instance, [download this working example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations) and open it in Chrome from your local machine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
</p>

<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 2</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 3</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2><a id="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now [save it as an MHTML file](https://superuser.com/questions/369232/how-to-save-a-web-page-as-mht-in-chrome) and try opening that MHTML version from your local machine. The hyperlink *does not* respond to a left mouse click.

However, the link *will* work if you:

- manually type the hyperlink into the address bar:
  `file:///C:/Users/usr/Desktop/test.html#C4`
- right click on the hyperlink and select "open in new tab"

So clearly the link still exists, which is further evidenced by hovering over it:

[image]

So why can't a left mouse click trigger the hyperlink like it did for the .html version?

This problem doesn't seem to exist for IE (at least for this example) and I have chrome `Version 35.0.1916.114 m`. It would be nice to know a general, platform independent solution to not restrict which browser is used to open the MHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use singlefile, a chrome extension found on the Chrome store, it produces MHTML files

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle

Comment: in conclusion, the MHTML parser I was using seems to be not quite sufficient which makes sense since it's still under development by google. Your link there gives a much more robust version, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Many years later, this is still THE answer, and just solved this problem for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987380