# Is it possible to package multiple HTML files in an MHTML file and navigate between them?

Tags: html, mhtml

So I might be thinking of the wrong file format, but I remember as a kid opening files that looked like a Windows 98 help window:

[image: Windows 98 help window]

I thought it was an MHTML file, and it allowed me to navigate between the packaged pages. Am I thinking of the right format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MHTML allows HTML with links as a standalone file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102712/how-to-create-mhtml-standalone-file-with-same-page-links). Many online tools will create one for you.

.MHT files are also single HTML files.

Winfows 98 actually used a [compiled HTML file](http://www.helpscribble.com/htmlhelp.html) -  ie a .CHM

Comment: But I can't have multiple HTML pages with one master page, and then link between the different pages inside the MHTML? I ask because each page can have from 10 to about 100 IFrames in it and I don't want to load those all at once, even if I use fancy JavaScript to hide each 'page' until called in one HTML file.

Comment: And *that's** the extension I was thinking of! But man, just the name 'Compiled HTML File' sounds gross.

Comment: Honestly don't even remember what my use case was for asking this, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

When I needed something similar, I created a [frameset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) in `main.htm` file like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>My framed webpage</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="25%,*">
    <frame src="toc.htm">
    <frame src="content.htm" name="content">
</frameset>

</html>
```

- `toc.htm` - table of contents, a list of links referred to `content.htm` file by id (with list of elements `<a href="content.htm#toc_0" target="content">Link Title Name</a>` with ids `toc_0` ... `toc_n`). Right frame in result file.
- `content.htm` - content file with links with ids `toc_0` ... `toc_n` you want to refer to. They might be any `h*` elements. Left frame in result file.

If you use Java, then [Jsoup](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup) is your best friend.

> `<frameset>` tag is deprecated HTML tag The  tag is not supported in HTML5

**UPD**. When you have three files `main.htm`, `toc.htm` and `content.htm` just open a main one. Previously there was a flag in Chrome experimental features to save as a MHTL and you had only to activate it, but now seems they [have removed it](https://techdows.com/2019/06/google-removes-save-page-as-mhtml-flag-from-chrome.html).
However you can use a [Save as MHTML add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-mhtml/ahgakckdonjmnpnegjcamhagackmjpei?hl=en) instead.

Comment: Is the source above the `nav.htm` or the `file.htm`? How do you save those both in an MHTML file?

Comment: The source above it third file `main.htm`. I have updated the answer and made links more self-explanatory so that `file.htm` is now `content.htm` and `nav.htm` is now `toc.htm`.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! I'll have to figure out my original use case and try it out.