# How to rewrite absolute links in a MHT file to become relative links (that point to the MHT file itself)?

Tags: html, hyperlink, mhtml

I have a result from a [web page](https://people.f4.htw-berlin.de/%7Eweberwu/simtexter/app.html) that is [saved as an MHT file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qzTryhGsoBbD1ub5Luld82prPrJsW93F/view?usp=sharing).

The MHT file works fine overall when opened in Chrome or Edge, for example. Only the contained links do not work, because they refer to the source of the web page, and not to the MHT file itself.

The links in question all have the following structure:

`<a id=3D "2-3721" class=3D "hl-0" href=3D "https://people.f4.htw-berlin.de/~weberwu/simtexter/app.html#1-1854">`

This syntax makes **links in the left half (#1)** of the page point to **targets in the right half (#2)** of the page, and vice versa.

I have already tried to rewrite all corresponding links in the MHT file by deleting the absolute address:

`https://people.f4.htw-berlin.de/~weberwu/simtexter/app.html`

which makes the links look as in the following example:

`<a id=3D "2-3721" class=3D "hl-0" href=3D "#1-1854">`

However, the links still do not work.

How can I rewrite or parse the links to make them work inside the MHT file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved if the website is not downloaded as MHT with the built-in Chrome parser, but with the Chrome Extension [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle), see also here:

[How to create MHTML standalone file with same page links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102712)